# Trying to get the division with the highest sales

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a program that show the quarterly sales for 6 different divisions in a company.

I have most of it working, but when I try to display the division with the highest sales in each quarter it isn't working.

EDIT: I got all the outputs to read correctly, but my issue now is checking if the number entered is >= 0, I've tried If statements and while loops and do while loops, but I can't figure it out.

EDIT 2: I have updated the code to match my current code.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class SalesByQuarter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int divs = 6; 
        int qtrs = 4; 
        double totalSales = 0.0;  
        double errorCheck;

    double[][] sales = new double[divs][qtrs];


    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("This program will calculate the " +
                       "total sales of");
    System.out.println("all the company's divisions. " +
                       "Enter the following sales data:");

    System.out.println();



        for (int div = 0; div < divs; div++)
        {
            for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++)
            {
                System.out.printf("Division %d, Quarter %d: $",
                                (div + 1), (qtr + 1));
                errorCheck = keyboard.nextDouble();
                sales[div][qtr] = errorCheck;
            }
            System.out.println();   
        }


        if (errorCheck < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Positive numbers only please!");
            for (int div = 0; div < divs; div++)
            {
                for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++)
                {
                    System.out.printf("Division %d, Quarter %d: $",
                                    (div + 1), (qtr + 1));
                    errorCheck = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    sales[div][qtr] = errorCheck;
                }
                System.out.println();   
            }
        }

        else
        {
            for (int div = 0; div < divs; div++)
            {
                for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++)
                {
                    totalSales += sales[div][qtr];
                }
            }


            double[] divsales = new double[divs];


            for (int div = 0; div < divs; div++)
            {
                for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++)
                {
                    divsales[div] += sales[div][qtr];
                }
                System.out.printf("Division %d sales: $%,.2f\n", (div + 1), divsales[div]);
            }


            System.out.println();


            for (int div = 1; div < divs; div++)
            {
                if ((divsales[div] - divsales[div - 1]) > 0)
                {
                    System.out.printf("Division %d increase over its previous quarter: $%,.2f\n", (div + 1), divsales[div] - divsales[(div - 1)]);
                }
                else if ((divsales[div] - divsales[div - 1]) < 0)
                {
                    System.out.printf("Division %d decrease from its previous quarter: $%,.2f\n", (div + 1), divsales[div] - divsales[(div - 1)]);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.printf("Division %d had no increase or decrease from its previous quarter.\n", (div + 1));
                }
            }


            System.out.println();


            double[] qtrsales = new double[qtrs];


            for (int div = 0; div < divs; div++)
            {
                for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++)
                {
                    qtrsales[qtr] += sales[div][qtr];
                }
            }




            for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++)
            {
                System.out.printf("Total sales for quarter: %d: $%,.2f\n", (qtr + 1), qtrsales[qtr]);
            }


            System.out.println();


            for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++)
            {
                System.out.printf(" Average sale for quarter: %d: $%,.2f\n", (qtr + 1), (qtrsales[qtr] / divs));
            }


            System.out.println();


            int highestDiv = 0;
            int[] highestDivi = new int[qtrs];
            for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++)
            {
                highestDiv = 0;
                for (int div = 0; div < (divs - 1); div++)
                {
                    if (sales[highestDiv][qtr] < sales[(div + 1)][qtr])
                    {
                        highestDiv = (div + 1);
                    }
                }
                highestDivi[qtr] = highestDiv;
            }

            for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++)
            {
                System.out.printf("Division %d had the highest sales in quarter %d\n", qtr + 1, highestDivi[qtr] + 1);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your last `printf` text makes it look like you want to print just the division number and not its total sales but doesn't `highestDivi` hold sales values because of the lines above such as: `highestDivi[qtr] = sales[div + 1][qtr]`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You are correct, Which is why I came here for help:/

Comment: Well for starters you don't need an array to keep track of the highest value  You just need a double variable (we only care about the quarter we are working on). Then maintain the division number in an int[] and you should be able to make it work. But your boolean logic in the loops there makes no sense either so you need to carefully rethink what that logic needs to accomplish.

Comment: I have a new issue, care to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a few semantic errors. I changed the part where you find the division with the highest sales per quarter.

```
int highestDivi[] = new int[qtrs];

double highestDiv = 0;
for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++)
{
    highestDiv = 0;
    for (int div = 0; div < divs; div++)
    {
        if (highestDiv < sales[div][qtr])
        {
            highestDivi[qtr] = div;
            highestDiv=sales[div][qrt];
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding EDIT 2:
I changed the part where the user inputs the sales, you should remove the error checking if-statement in your code.

```
for (int div = 0; div < divs; div++)
{
    for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++)
    {
        System.out.printf("Division %d, Quarter %d: $",
                        (div + 1), (qtr + 1));
        errorCheck = keyboard.nextDouble();
        while(errorCheck<0) {
            System.out.println("Positive numbers only please!");
            System.out.printf("Division %d, Quarter %d: $",
                        (div + 1), (qtr + 1));
            errorCheck = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }
        sales[div][qtr] = errorCheck;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Everything should look like the following

```
public class SalesByQuarter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int divs = 6; 
        int qtrs = 4; 
        double totalSales = 0.0;  
        double errorCheck;

    double[][] sales = new double[divs][qtrs];


    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("This program will calculate the " +
                       "total sales of");
    System.out.println("all the company's divisions. " +
                       "Enter the following sales data:");

    System.out.println();


        for (int div = 0; div < divs; div++)
        {
            for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++)
            {
                System.out.printf("Division %d, Quarter %d: $",
                                (div + 1), (qtr + 1));
                errorCheck = keyboard.nextDouble();
                while(errorCheck<0) {
                    System.out.println("Positive numbers only please!");
                    System.out.printf("Division %d, Quarter %d: $",
                                (div + 1), (qtr + 1));
                    errorCheck = keyboard.nextDouble();
                }
                sales[div][qtr] = errorCheck;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }





        for (int div = 0; div < divs; div++)
        {
            for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++)
            {
                totalSales += sales[div][qtr];
            }
        }


        double[] divsales = new double[divs];


        for (int div = 0; div < divs; div++)
        {
            for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++)
            {
                divsales[div] += sales[div][qtr];
            }
            System.out.printf("Division %d sales: $%,.2f\n", (div + 1), divsales[div]);
        }


        System.out.println();


        for (int div = 1; div < divs; div++)
        {
            if ((divsales[div] - divsales[div - 1]) > 0)
            {
                System.out.printf("Division %d increase over its previous quarter: $%,.2f\n", (div + 1), divsales[div] - divsales[(div - 1)]);
            }
            else if ((divsales[div] - divsales[div - 1]) < 0)
            {
                System.out.printf("Division %d decrease from its previous quarter: $%,.2f\n", (div + 1), divsales[div] - divsales[(div - 1)]);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.printf("Division %d had no increase or decrease from its previous quarter.\n", (div + 1));
            }
        }


        System.out.println();


        double[] qtrsales = new double[qtrs];


        for (int div = 0; div < divs; div++)
        {
            for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++)
            {
                qtrsales[qtr] += sales[div][qtr];
            }
        }




        for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++)
        {
            System.out.printf("Total sales for quarter: %d: $%,.2f\n", (qtr + 1), qtrsales[qtr]);
        }


        System.out.println();


        for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++)
        {
            System.out.printf(" Average sale for quarter: %d: $%,.2f\n", (qtr + 1), (qtrsales[qtr] / divs));
        }


        System.out.println();


        int highestDiv = 0;
        int[] highestDivi = new int[qtrs];
        for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++)
        {
            highestDiv = 0;
            for (int div = 0; div < (divs - 1); div++)
            {
                if (sales[highestDiv][qtr] < sales[(div + 1)][qtr])
                {
                    highestDiv = (div + 1);
                }
            }
            highestDivi[qtr] = highestDiv;
        }

        for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++)
        {
            System.out.printf("Division %d had the highest sales in quarter %d\n", qtr + 1, highestDivi[qtr] + 1);
        }

    }

}
```

Cheers!

Comment: `highestDiv` is an `int`, but you're comparing it to `sales[div][qtr]`, which is a double. Are you sure that's what you mean?

Comment: QuarterSales.java:166: error: cannot find symbol
                                        highestDiv=sales[div][qrt];
                                                              ^
  symbol:   variable qrt
  location: class QuarterSales
QuarterSales.java:166: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from
 double to int
                                        highestDiv=sales[div][qrt];
                                                             ^
2 errors

Comment: I need to output the highest division as an int, it needs to be 1-6.

Comment: I have a new issue, care to help?

Comment: There was an issue. I put in all positive numbers, but it gave the error message and had me enter ever number again.

Comment: Let me know if you still have an issue.